# text preview feature does not work anymore after upgrade to El Captain

Tags: mac, preview, bibdesk

I am using a MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) running OS X 10.11. After having  upgraded to El Captain, Bibdesk is not producing anymore the preview of my bibliographic entries. How can I visualize again the bibliographic entries with Text Preview?
here is the message error as it appear in the the log.

> --------- BibDesk info ----------
>
> {
>
> ivars:
>
> delegate = ""
>
> file name = "bibpreview"
>
> template = "/Users/giancarlodiano/Library/Application
>   Support/BibDesk/previewtemplate.tex"
>
> TeX file =
>   "/var/folders/3n/xtr1kkrx5bz4vmcxy_5f77gm0000gn/T/bibdesk.tj3vqg/bibpreview/bibpreview.tex"
>
> BibTeX file =
>   "/var/folders/3n/xtr1kkrx5bz4vmcxy_5f77gm0000gn/T/bibdesk.tj3vqg/bibpreview/bibpreview.bib"
>
> TeX binary path = "/usr/texbin"
>
> Encoding = "Western (ASCII)"
>
> BibTeX style = "abbrv"
>
> Helper files = (
>
> )
>
> environment:
>
> SHELL = "/bin/bash"
>
> BIBINPUTS = "(null)"
>
> BSTINPUTS = "(null)"
>
> TEXINPUTS = "(null)"
>
> TEXCONFIG = "(null)"
>
> TEXMFCONFIG = "(null)"
>
> PATH = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" }

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked at other question that speek about the el capitan update? There is a change of path that can cause conflict

Comment: I did, but unfortunately did not help..

Comment: Please, paste the log, select it and click the `{}` button rather than the button for quotations.

Comment: Ok , will do for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the preferences of BibDesk and go to the “TeX preview” panel; in the two boxes change `/usr/texbin` into `/Library/TeX/texbin` to get

[image]

Here's the end of the log after generating a preview (I just masked my user name):

```
---------- BibDesk info ----------
<BDSKTeXTask: 0x60000028d8e0> {
ivars:
    delegate = "<BDSKPreviewer: 0x600000321ea0>"
    file name = "bibpreview"
    template = "/Users/?????/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/previewtemplate.tex"
    TeX file = "/var/folders/8b/hx9v58ln1txgzv4v32_vpbr40000gn/T/bibdesk.twW03T/bibpreview/bibpreview.tex"
    BibTeX file = "/var/folders/8b/hx9v58ln1txgzv4v32_vpbr40000gn/T/bibdesk.twW03T/bibpreview/bibpreview.bib"
    TeX binary path = "/Library/TeX/texbin"
    Encoding = "Unicode (UTF-8)"
    BibTeX style = "abbrv"
    Helper files = (
)

environment:
    SHELL = "/bin/bash"
    BIBINPUTS = "(null)"
    BSTINPUTS = "(null)"
    TEXINPUTS = "(null)"
    TEXCONFIG = "(null)"
    TEXMFCONFIG = "(null)"
    PATH = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" }
```

Comment: @CarloDiano So, why did you accept the answer? There can be many more reasons why the preview generation has failed, the log is usually informative.

Comment: You were right the first time!  I misspelled the path and that's why you solution was "not working", once I caught my own mistake, it worked!